# jQuery div fading out onload issue

Tags: jquery

i'm having a very frustrating problem.
Basically my intention was to animate a div on click using the .toggle() class in jQuery. 
The problem is that on-load the div just disappears! i really can't figure it out why... (the actual script has ended at the end of CSS code section of code below, i don't know why)

[Here's JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gfbg5h1d/)

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <!-- NAV -->

    <!-- SLIDER ONE-->
    <div class="container-fluid slides" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
        <!-- SLIDER ONE-->
        <div class="slider-one1 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="slider-one2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- SLIDER TWO-->
        <div class="slider-two1 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="slider-two2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>

    </div>


    <!-- cookies notificaton -->
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }


.slides div:hover {
  opacity: 0.8; }


.slider-one1 {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer; }


.slider-one2 {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0; }


.slider-two1 {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0; }


.slider-two2 {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 0; }
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(window).ready(function(){
       $(".slider-one1").toggle(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: "98vw"
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
             width: "50vw"
        }, 500);
    });

    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of jQuery? Your fiddle doesn't have one set. (Click on the "JAVASCRIPT (gear)" to set)

Comment: `toggle()` no longer works in that manner. You need to handle the successive clicks yourself

Comment: Its disappearing because you are toggling it when doms ready. You should code this inside click listener function.

Comment: Oh that explains everything.... i've seen a code where the toggle method was used as .click() too but that was probably old. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `ready` function for `window`, it should be `document` instead of window.

```
$(document).ready(function(){.....});
```

**UPDATED**

For animations avoid `.animate()` of jquery it will make your code more complex, write `css` classes instead and use `css transitions` for animations here is a **demo**.

```
.animate1 {
  width: 98vw !important;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
 transition:all 0.5s ease; 
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".slider-one1").click(function(){   
        $(this).toggleClass("animate1");
   });

});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/gfbg5h1d/7/)**

Comment: Thank you! My mistake. But still the div disappears after click instead of becoming longer :\

Comment: Thank you for your help Tanzil :) Really appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Because you trig the toggle on document ready instead of click.

Then if you wanna expand end restore on click your code should be liek this

$(".slider-one1").on('click',function(){
   $(this).animate({
        width: "98vw"
    }, 500, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
         width: "50vw"
    }, 500);
});
});

if instead you wanna to expand on first click and restore on second click (keeping track of the state) you need something like this

```
var state = false;

$(".slider-one1").on('click',function(){
    if(!state){
   $(this).animate({
        width: "98vw"
    }, 500);
    state = true;
    }
  else{
    $(this).animate({
         width: "50vw"
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/gfbg5h1d/8/) (solution 2)

Comment: I've now understood how to make it stay! but it still disappears after click instead of becoming longer :\

Comment: Is your target  first click expand, second click restore? Or do you wanna expand and restore on same click (like a beat) ?

Comment: yes! that's what i was trying to achieve :)
First click expand second click restore

Comment: Thank you for your help Luca :) Really appriciated